# Revit Python Shell - Get cost property from Elements in a Revit sheet

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

I'm new to the Revit API, and I would like to experiment with a sheet to get the `cost` property of a simple sheet that has 4 walls:

[image]

[image]

Do you know if doing this using the Revit API is possible? My idea is to get all property cost for any element in a sheet (Walls, windows, doors, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. Probably the cost value is stored in a `Parameter` on a Revit database `Element`. You can use [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) and other database exploration tools to view, navigate and explore the BIM element parameters, properties and relationships to find out how to access it programmatically.